# react-router-dom v6 for google analytics

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, react-router-dom

So in a previous application for using Google Analytics i had this component for a `<RouteChangeTracker/>` this component would listen to the url change, and that would be passed to ReactGA so GA knew which page the users were on and looking at. However in `react-router-dom` v6 these features are missing, well, not missing but they've moved the functionality into `useLocation` and `useNavigate` but the methods attached to them have changed, im trying to refactor the component to be usuable in `v6` Can someone help me here?

here is the code from the previous setup

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ReactGA from "react-ga";

const RouteChangetracker = ({ history }) => {
  history.listen((location, action) => {
    ReactGA.set({ page: location.pathname });
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname);
  });

  return <div></div>;
};

export default withRouter(RouteChangetracker);
```

I need to refactor this into a `v6` setup, I tried changing out history for `useLocation` but it doesnt have the same effect..

Answer (score 1):

This should be achievable using `useLocation`, there's even an [example](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.7.0/hooks/use-location) of it being implemented along with ga.

This new hook will update on each change in history, from there the `pathname` can be extracted.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  let location = useLocation();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Google Analytics
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  }, [location]);

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

Comment: links are broken

Comment: I've updated the official documentation. The example there is the same as the previous stackblitz broken one

Answer (score -1):

i have the same problem.

in the index.html resolve with

I still haven't been able to solve it any other way

```
<script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXX"
    ></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag("js", new Date());

      gtag("config", "G-XXXXX");
    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).